# Why replace in this code approves float numbers as numeric . I have tried floats without replace and I am getting message that it is not a number

Tags: python, if-statement, input, replace, isnumeric

```
#user inputs a number
number = input("Enter number: ")
# 1) changes dot and creates a new string,2) verifies is it a number
if(not number.replace(".","").isnumeric()):
    print("Sorry number is not numeric")
```

> Generally **replace** changes old value with a new one.

Comment: `isnumeric` checks all the characters in the string are numbers.  The character `.` is not a number so `isnumeric` returns `False` for strings with decimal points in them.

Comment: @PeterWood, Thanks Peter. Now I figured out that replace('.','') means removing dot and making it to be valid(number) after isnumeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isnumeric` returns True if and only if every *character* of the string is a numeric character [as defined by Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode). Periods are not numeric, but many characters that contain or represent numbers, such as `½` or `六`, are considered numeric.

First, you probably want `isdigit` instead, because a lot of the numeric characters in Unicode aren't valid in float numbers. `isdigit` only returns True if every character is one of the ASCII digits 0-9.

Second, to validate if the input is a float, it's "Better to Ask Forgiveness than Permission": try converting it as a float directly, and see if that fails:

```py
try:
    float(number)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry number is not a float")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number = input("Enter number: ")
if(not number.replace(".","").isnumeric()):
    print("Sorry number is not numeric")
```

> **Replace** here change dot, creates a new string and makes **isnumeric()** to be True for float numbers.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that you have a valid float at the end. For example, `1.1.1` and `六.六` pass this filter, even though neither is a valid float. And, valid floats like `1e3` and `-2.6` fail the filter.

Comment: @nneonneo, Yes, you're right. for E.g. -2.6 as you said I have if float(odd1)<=1: print('less than 1'). For regular floats with one dot will work , correct?

Comment: The syntax for floats is not straightforward, and a simple check even with `isdigit` and a single dot would not suffice. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals for the full syntax for floats. This is why I recommended just trying to parse the float using `float()` in my answer.

Comment: I've read the documentation. You are right, the best option to parse is using **float()**.